# How to find a specific file in a folder?

Tags: c

So i tried something and everything works fine if the file i'm searching doesn't have an extension in its name (i have a txt file named "instructions" and a fifo file named "myfifo" and they were found).

```c
struct dirent *de=NULL;
DIR *dirr=NULL;

dirr=opendir(".");
while((de=readdir(dirr)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n",de->d_name);
    if (strcmp(de->d_name,file)==0) printf("Found!\n");
    // else printf("kkbesa\n");
}
```

the variable "file" is declared as char file[100] and i read it from the keyboard.
As i mentioned above, for the files "myfifo" and "instructions" it printed "Found", but when i go for something like "code.c" or "code.exe" it doesn't print anything(Yes, they exist in the current folder).

Comment: I'd like to find a way to print "Found" even for "code.c" or "code.exe" type of files.

Comment: Could you give the full program.  I don't see anything strange at first sight and fear an issue in the initialization of `file`.

Comment: Could also be a case-sensitivity issue: `code.exe` implies that you are probably on Windows and the file system is not case-sensitive. `strcmp`, however, is case-sensitive. So if the file is actually `CODE.EXE` (which may be shown in lowercase by Windows!), it won't match `code.exe` with `strcmp`.

Comment: How did you read the filename from the keyboard? If you used `fgets`, did you account for the newline at the end of the string?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. The origin of your problem is probably in the code you didn't show here.